# Wcf Rest Service - serialize or hand-craft xml?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, serialization

I'm putting together a plan for an Xml web service to go into a client's site to be consumed by third-parties so that they can access the client's data.

My question is really asking about best practises here, and at the moment I am deliberating over 2 different strategies:

1) Create an object model which represents my Xml data and serialize it (either explicitly, or  implicitly by exposing the data through a Wcf REST endpoint)

2) Transforming my domain model directly into hand-crafted Xml using XLinq and returning this as a string from the service, setting up the response headers appropriately

I like (1) because I let the system do the generation of the physical Xml and I work purely within the object model, but versioning becomes a problem and I might need finer control over the output.

I like (2) because I do get the fine control and versioning becomes easier, but I'm now hand-crafting Xml and the opportunity for error escalates.

Any opinions? Am I missing something which gives me the best of both worlds? I would go straight for (1) if I knew the best way to 'version an object model' - would using different namespaces suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use serialization. As long as you don't try to use your domain objects for serialization you can get pretty fine grained control over the XML either via the DataContractSerializer or the XmlSerializer. You can then map between your domain objects and your serialization objects using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: In that case, do you have any comment on the subject of versioning? I guess it would be fine if your changes are additive, but how do you account for breaking changes using this model, and being able to provide a new revision of the schema to your clients?

Comment: If the change is breaking there are a number of things you can do - the most robust and simplest is to use a new endpoint for the new version of the service - old clients talk to the old one and new clients talk to the new one. If that won't work for you then possibly have another method with a new action that the new requests go to. Finally you could  map the operation to a method that takes Message as a parameter and fork your processing based on, say XML namespace or similar (you can still run the serializer against the appropriate type yourself

Comment: The main thing is that breaking changes will require two different versions of the serialization type

Comment: Thanks. It's more the serialization type question I'm interested in - I'm exploring whether I would need to create another version of my model in a different namespace to support it. From what you've just said, I would..

Comment: Yes you would need a new type for serialization